# Vim: Is there a way to generate an auto-increment sequence of numbers using vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

What I want is a sequence like "1 & 1.5 & 2 & 2.5 & 3 & 3.5 & 4".

I have found out that `:for i in range(1,10)|put='& '.i|endfor` can generate a sequence of numbers. The problem is that it won't accept decimals as step length and it will generate a line feed automatically. I've also tried vim macro. Again, the ctrl+a command would increase the selected number by 1 instead of 0.5.

PS: I'm not a native English speaker. I hope you can understand what I mean. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you accept the answer. I think it is an perfect one.

Comment: Terribly sorry. I did't know how to accept an answer lol. I'm new here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the .5 by dividing by 2.0

```
:put=map(range(5), 'v:val/2.0')
```

You'll need `join()` to add the ampersand in between

```
:put=join(map(range(5), 'v:val/2.0'), ' & ')
```